# Convergence in $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ implies convergence in $L^1(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

When working with a problem in Evans' book, I have the following problem:

> Assume $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Suppose that a sequence of functions $u_n \in L^p(\Omega)$ convergence in $L^1(\omega)$ to $u \in L^p(\Omega)$ for every $\omega$ compactly contained in $\Omega$.
>
> Is it true that $u_n \to u$ in $L^p(\Omega)$?

The converse is easy, but I can't find a proof, or a counterexample for the question.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Is $L^1(\omega)$ supposed to be $L^p(\omega)$?

Comment: In any event, you can probably approximate $\Omega$ by finitely many disjoint $\omega$'s, where the approximation is good enough so that the integral over the part of $\Omega$ not covered by the $\omega$'s has small integral with respect to $u$.

Comment: You could consider $n^2x^n$ on $(0,1).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f_n=\frac1{n^{1/p}} \chi_{[n,2n]}$. Then in any compact set $\omega$ you have that $f_n\to 0$ in $L^p$ or $L^1$ but the sequence does not converge to zero in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.